# Can I use same class name for multiple Ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I have written a code that updates `score1`, `score2` into the database, using jQuery.

My jQuery/AJAX code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#SampleForm').submit(
    function(event) {
      var id = $('.id').val();
      var score1 = $('.score1').val();
      var score2 = $('.score2').val();
      var data = 'score1=' + score1 + '&score2=' + score2 + '&id=' + id;
      $.ajax({
        url: $("#SampleForm").attr("action"),
        data: data,
        type: "GET",

        success: function(response) {
          alert(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
      });
      return false;
      location.reload(true)
    });
});
```

The JSP Code is

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${userinuser}">
  <form action="/mark/update" method="get" id="SampleForm">
    <input type="hidden" value="${item.userScores.ID}" name="id" class="id" />
    <input type="text" value="${item.userScores.score1}" name="score1" class="score1" size="2">
    <input type="text" value="${item.userScores.score2}" name="score2" class="score2" size="2">
    <input type="submit" value="update" class="btn btn-primary" />
  </form>
</c:forEach>
```

And assume `${userinuser}` is 6, then 6 forms will be generated dynamically in this JSP Page.
All the 6 forms use the same class name for score1 as `score1` and score2 as `score2`.

My AJAX call is working for the first time (first dynamically generated form), but it doesn't works for the remaining 5 AJAX calls.

I know this way of coding will not be suitable for application

Can any one suggest me an good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.submit` event attaches the form that is submitted to the `this`. You can use that to specify in which form jQuery needs to look for the class.

```js
$('.SampleForm').submit(function(event) {
  var score1 = $('.score1', this).val();
  var score2 = $('.score2', this).val();

  console.log('score1', score1);
  console.log('score2', score2);

  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/mark/update" method="get" class="SampleForm">
  <input type="hidden" value="${item.userScores.ID}" name="id" class="id" />
  <input type="text" value="1" name="score1" class="score1" size="2">
  <input type="text" value="2" name="score2" class="score2" size="2">
  <input type="submit" value="update" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>

<form action="/mark/update" method="get" class="SampleForm">
  <input type="hidden" value="${item.userScores.ID}" name="id" class="id" />
  <input type="text" value="3" name="score1" class="score1" size="2">
  <input type="text" value="4" name="score2" class="score2" size="2">
  <input type="submit" value="update" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

Please do note that you can only use an `id` only one time in your document. Your `SampleForm` is invalid because it is used for all the forms.

Answer (score 2):

You are generating 6 forms with the same id `#SampleForm`. When there are multiple nodes with the same ID, the first one will always come up.

You could instead use a className for your form:

```
<form class="SampleForm">
```

And then listen for submission on any of them:

```
$('.SampleForm').submit(...)
```

However, you still have a second issue. You're trying to get the data using the classnames of the input elements, and the action attribute of the first form. You could instead do:

```
 $('.SampleForm').submit(function(event) {
   var data = $(this).serialize(),
       url = $(this).attr('action');

   $.ajax({
       url : url,
       data : data,
       type : "GET",
       ....
   });

   return false;
   location.reload(true)
})
```

Comment: where i have to put the code in JQuery "var data = $(this).serialize(),
       url = $(this).attr('action');"

Comment: Declare the data in the same place you're doing it now. Serializing the form will return a sentence just like the one you're manually building. The url can be placed after it, and then use it on your ajax call as `url: url` instead of `url: $("#SampleForm").attr("action")`